# Solving a challenge in JAVA. The challenge is mentioned below in the description. The logical bug I am facing is also in the description below

Tags: java

Lukáš really likes orienteering, a sport that requires locating control points in rough terrain. To entertain the NWERC participants Lukáš wants to organize an orienteering race. However, it would be too harsh for the participants to be outdoors in this cold Swedish November weather, so he decided to jump on the new trend of indoor races, and set the race inside the B building of Linköping University.

Lukáš has already decided on the locations of the control points. He has also decided on the exact length of the race, so the only thing remaining is to decide in which order the control points should be visited such that the length of the total race is as he wishes. Because this is not always possible, he asks you to write a program to help him.

Input Format

The input consists of:

one line with two integers n (2 ≤ n ≤ 14) and L (1 ≤ L ≤ 1015), the number of control points and the desired length of the race, respectively;
n lines with n integers each. The jth integer on the ith line, dij , denotes the distance between control point i and j (1 ≤ dij ≤ L for i 6= j, and dii = 0). For all 1 ≤ i, j, k ≤ N it is the case that dij = dji and dij ≤ dik + dkj .
Output Format

Output one line with “possible” if it is possible to visit all control points once in some order and directly return to the first one such that the total distance is exactly L, and “impossible” otherwise.

Sample Input

```
3 5
0 1 3
1 0 3
4 1 0
```

Sample Output

```
possible
```

**The problem with the code is that the for loop in else loop of function *checkscenario()* only considers the first iteration and returns false as a result. It doesn't check the next iteration which will return true and thus give the proper solution.**

***Lets use the sample input for the explanation. Initially, the function gets value of the parameters as follows :-***

controlptsleft = {0,1,2,3}

> //These are the control pts which haven't been visited.

index = 0;

> //This is the control pt that I am at.

controlmatrix  =

```
0 1 3
1 0 3
4 1 0
```

L = 5

> //The desired length.

sum = 0

> //Till now we haven't trailed the control pts. So, sum = 0.

```
    public static boolean checkscenario(ArrayList<Integer> controlptsleft, int index, int[][] controlmatrix, int L, int sum){
        int row = controlptsleft.get(index);
        //row stores the value in the ArrayList controlptsleft at the index.
        controlptsleft.remove(index);
        //The controlpt is removed. The first time 0 will be removed from arrayList controlptsleft.
        if(controlptsleft.isEmpty()){
            //When the ArrayList controlptsleft is empty, we have to go back to the first controlflag.
            int temp = controlmatrix[row][0];
            //temp stores the distance between the control flag where we are at and the starting control flag.
            if(L == (sum + temp))
                return true;
        }
        else{
            for(int i=0;i<controlptsleft.size();i++){
                int temp = controlmatrix[row][controlptsleft.get(i)];
                //temp stores the distance between the control flag where we are at and the whatever controlflag we get during the iteration.
                ArrayList<Integer> tempList = controlptsleft;
                boolean finalres = checkscenario(tempList,i,controlmatrix,L,(sum + temp));
                //Here, i is sent so that when it enters the function again the index i (along with the value) in ArrayList tempList will be deleted.
                if(finalres)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You would do better to remove the boilerplate piece about the assignment *out* of the question, and only focus on the part that you're actually concerned about.  I only skimmed it and made an assumption about what you were asking based on that alone, which isn't really all that great but is *very* common anyway.

Comment: It's very difficult to keep track of this code with non-descriptive variable names (e.g. `n`, `L`, `temp`). It would be much easier to understand if you change that.

Comment: `controlptsleft.remove(index);` and `for(int i=0;i<controlptsleft.size();i++) { ... }` is calling for trouble in this case. Note that `ArrayList<Integer> tempList = controlptsleft;` does not work as you expect: It *does not* make a copy of the list! Hence, all recursive calls operate on the very same list, and that's not really what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone out there wants to know, I figured out the answer for this challenge.

First of all, i would like to thank ***Hanno Binder*** for that comment. I realized where I went wrong.

Inside the else loop of the function ***checkscenario***

```
else{
        for(int i=0;i<controlptsleft.size();i++){
        int temp = controlmatrix[row][controlptsleft.get(i)];
        ArrayList<Integer> tempList = controlptsleft;
        boolean finalres = checkscenario(tempList,i,controlmatrix,L,(sum + temp));
        if(finalres)
            return true;
    }
```

What I did was, I directly copied the reference of ***controlptsleft*** to ***tempList***. I realized the bug and I instead initialized ***tempList*** and used ***.addAll*** to put all the values from ***controlptsleft*** to ***tempList***.
The following code illustrates what I meant above.

```
else{
        for(int i=0;i<controlptsleft.size();i++){
            int temp = controlmatrix[row][controlptsleft.get(i)];
            ArrayList<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            tempList.addAll(controlptsleft);
            boolean finalres = checkscenario(tempList,i,controlmatrix,L,(sum + temp));
            if(finalres)
                return true;
        }
    }
```

If someone has a better solution in JAVA for the challenge mentioned above. Feel free to post their code, so I could learn how to code better.